# iPhone not turning on when pressing lock button/erroneous charging

Tags: battery, iphone

When I try to turn on my phone by holding the lock button, it doesn't turn on. It just stays dead.

But when I connect the Lightning cable, all it does is show the battery symbol, then go to the Apple logo, and repeats.

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like a battery issue. How old is your phone?

Comment: Agreed, if it keeps returning to the battery screen it's loosing the minimum amount of power to boot up. Did you leave the phone discharged for an extended period of time? Can you make sure you're charging via a 2.1A USB charger? This may prevent the lack of charging.

Answer (score 1):

Let it charge overnight, if the behavior is the same you could try another charger and/or cable as it is *possible* that you have a bad charger or cable.

Failing all of that it is likely that the battery in the phone is kaput and needs to be replaced.

If you are in warranty, take it to an Apple store. If it is not in warranty you could do the same, or if you know of a reputable phone repair shop they can do it as well.